# TimHeuer's FloatableWindow Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, user-controls

I've some trouble with Tim's [FloatableWindow](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/). (<--SourceCode & DLLs)

It throws the following Exception once closed the control.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in System.Windows.Controls.FloatableWindow.b__0(Object s, EventArgs args)

in System.Windows.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)

in MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)

First I created a control by using the FloatableWindow template, And then i just created the Window on CodeBehind.

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        FloatableWindow1 f1 = new FloatableWindow1();//TheTemplatedOne
        f1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FloatableWindow f = new FloatableWindow();
        f.Height = 100;
        f.Width = 100;
        f.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But stills the same issue...

Im not trying to access any information on the Closed EventHandler.

Im running v3.0.40624.4 Release of the dll on SL v3.0.50106.0 in a C# project w/RiaServices

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by setting up the ParentLayout Property

```
f.ParentLayoutRoot = this.LayoutRoot;
```